# Redirect before loading the page in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I have a requirement that before the page is going to load i want to check whether query string exists or not if query string exists then i want to redirect to another page instead of current page how can i handle this type of requirement in JSF 2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Do you need it for GET or POST requests? For every request in your project? Or is it a redirect in an action method?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.before loading the home page i want to check whether the link is having query string or not if query strin exists then i want to validate that query string and if it is not valid query string then i will redirect to error page if validation sucess then i will show home page.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When on JSF 2.2, you can use `<f:viewAction>` for this.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="paramName" value="#{bean.paramName}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{bean.check}" />
</f:metadata>
```

*(`paramName` is the name of your query string parameter)*

```
private String paramName; // +getter+setter

public String check() {
    if (paramName == null) {
        return "error.xhtml";
    }

    return null;
}
```

When not on JSF 2.2 yet (JSF 2.0/2.1), you can use `<f:event type="preRenderView">` for this.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="paramName" value="#{bean.paramName}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.check}" />
</f:metadata>
```

```
private String paramName; // +getter+setter

public void check() throws IOException {
    if (paramName == null) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("error.xhtml");
    }
}
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-fviewparam-and-fviewaction-be-used-for)

Comment: Thank's Balusc for your quick response

Comment: just remember it is `<f:metadata>`, not `<f:metatata>`

Comment: @Valter: typo fixed, thanks.