# Warning: The page declares namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core no TagLibrary associated to namespace in JSF on TomEE

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2.2, apache-tomee

I'm trying to create a page that validates url parameters and redirects to error page when parameters are not present.

Developing on TomEE 1.7.3 and Eclipse. Project set to Development mode. I'm targeting JSF 2.2.

I've used these questions:

- [Redirect before loading the page in JSF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598375/redirect-before-loading-the-page-in-jsf2)
- [NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546219/nls-missing-message-cannot-find-facelet-taglib)

My code works, however I'm getting warnings on Eclipse and on Server:

[image]
[image]

How can I rid of these warnings? Will these show in Production environment too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, TomEE 1.7.x ships with JSF 2.1, not 2.2. The migrated `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace domain is only available since JSF 2.2. Unless you've manually upgraded TomEE itself to use JSF 2.2, this won't work at all and you should keep using `java.sun.com` XML namespace domain.

---

> *How can I rid of these warnings?*

Have a concrete JSF 2.2 implementation JAR file in project's *Build Path*. In case of Java EE servers, this is usually to be done by setting the server as *Targeted Runtime* in project's properties. The server plugin will then auto-reference server's own libraries in *Build Path*. Obviously, this will only work properly if the server plugin is decent and you have correctly upgraded the server itself to physically use JSF 2.2.

If this still doesn't work (because of poor server plugin), then download the individual JSF implementation JAR file, put it somewhere in project (but NOT in `/WEB-INF/lib`, otherwise it will conflict with server's own JSF impl during runtime and cause class/method/abstract related exceptions over all place), and add it to project's *Build Path*.

---

> *Will these show in Production environment too?*

I can't imagine how as production servers usually don't run server via an IDE and HTTP clients usually aren't able to monitor the server's VGA output.

Comment: Ouch. I was fooled by TomEE + Eclipse guide
http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html

Comment: I wanted to use f:event, but then an "Parent UIComponent should be instance of UIViewRoot" error occured. Seems like another story tho. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: If you're actually using TomEE 1.7.x own default JSF 2.1 implementation, just change XML namespace domain back from xmlns.jcp.org to java.sun.com as in `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`

Comment: I did, rolled to xmlns.jcp.org just to check if f:viewAction would work. Actually it worked and I thought its just environment configuration problem.